Segmentation Fault when using tf.data.Datasets
I'm new-ish to tensorflow, and I have a problem with tf.data.Datasets, in particular I load some big numpy arrays in a python dictionary in the following way:
for t in ['train', 'val', 'test']:
  try:
    array_dict[f'x_{t}'] = np.load(f'{self.folder}/x_{t}.npy',mmap_mode='c')
    array_dict[f'y_{t}'] = np.load(f'{self.folder}/y_{t}.npy',mmap_mode='c')
  except Exception as e:
    logger.error(f'Error loading {t} data: {e}')
    raise e

then in another part of the code I convert them in Datasets like so:
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((array_dict['x_train'], array_dict['y_train'], array_dict['weights'])).shuffle(1000).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((array_dict['x_val'], array_dict['y_val'])).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

and then feed these to a keras_tuner tuner to optimize my model hyperparameters. This brings to a segfault just after the training of the first tentative model starts.
The same happens with a normal keras.Sequential model, so the problem is not keras_tuner. I noticed that if I reduce the size of the arrays (taking for example only 1000 samples) it works for a bit, but still gives segfault. The training works fine with numpy arrays, but I cannot use all the resources needed to keep the full arrays in memory, so I was trying datasets to reduce the memory usage. Any advice on how to solve this or a better way to manage the memory usage? Thanks

What is "big"? A dataset from_tensor_slices is in no way more memory-efficient than numpy arrays. It just keeps the whole tensor in memory. So if loading the numpy arrays isn't feasible, neither will be a tensor dataset.
